# Curiously Recurring Template Pattern - Can't create more than 1 derived class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++14, static-polymorphism

I'm stuck using this pattern, because only one of the derived classes i have created gets instantiated. Checked with g++ and MSVS. Specifically only the first derived class I define gets created. No warnings of any kind are emitted by the compiler. Complete code is provided below.

```
#include <iostream>

static int nodes = 0;

class TreeNode {
private:
    int m_id;
public:
    TreeNode() : 
        m_id(++nodes)
    {}
    TreeNode(int id) :
        m_id(id)
    {
        ++nodes;
    }
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;

    int getId() const {
        return m_id;
    }
};


template<typename T>
//typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<TreeParser, T>::value>::type
class TreeParser {
protected:
    TreeParser() {
        ++parsers;
    }
public:
    static uint32_t parsers;
    void preorderTraversal(TreeNode* node) {
        if (node != nullptr) {
            processNode(node);
            preorderTraversal(node->left);
            preorderTraversal(node->right);
        }
    }
    virtual ~TreeParser() = default;

    void processNode(TreeNode* node) {              // 2, 3. the generic algorithm is customized by derived classes
        static_cast<T*>(this)->processNode(node);   // depending on the client's demand - the right function will be called
    }
};

template<class T>
uint32_t TreeParser<T>::parsers = 0;

class SpecializedTreeParser1 : public TreeParser<SpecializedTreeParser1> // 1. is-a relationship
{
public:
    explicit SpecializedTreeParser1() : 
        TreeParser()
    {}
    void processNode(TreeNode* node) {
        std::cout << "Customized (derived - SpecializedTreeParser1) processNode(node) - "
            "id=" << node->getId() << '\n';
    }
};

class SpecializedTreeParser2 : public TreeParser<SpecializedTreeParser2> // 1. is-a relationship
{
public:
    explicit SpecializedTreeParser2() : 
        TreeParser()
    {}
    void processNode(TreeNode* node) {
        std::cout << "Customized (derived - SpecializedTreeParser2) processNode(node) - "
            "id=" << node->getId() << '\n';
    }
};


int main() 
{
    TreeNode root;
    TreeNode leftChild;
    TreeNode rightChild;

    root.left = &leftChild;
    root.right = &rightChild;

    std::cout << "Root id: " << root.getId() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Left child id: " << leftChild.getId() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Right child id: " << rightChild.getId() << '\n';

    SpecializedTreeParser1 _1;
    _1.preorderTraversal(&root);

    SpecializedTreeParser2 _2;
    _2.preorderTraversal(&root);
}
```

The output is:

```
Root id: 1
Left child id: 2
Right child id: 3
Customized (derived - SpecializedTreeParser1) preorderTraversal() - id=1
Customized (derived - SpecializedTreeParser1) preorderTraversal() - id=2
Customized (derived - SpecializedTreeParser1) preorderTraversal() - id=1963060099 // what is that?
```

Why can't I instantiate the second derived class?

Comment: have you stepped thought it using a debugger? doesn't seem like TreeNode's left or right are initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I I'm not mistaken, your program has undefined behavior. The `left` and `right` pointers of `leftChild` and `rightChild` are left uninitialized, so as soon as `preorderTraversal()` gets there, your program blows up. That's also why you get the weird `id` in the end: it's reading from some random memory location…

To solve this problem, make sure the `left` and `right` members of a `TreeNode` are always initialized to `nullptr` as the rest of your code seems to expect:

```
class TreeNode {
    …
    TreeNode* left = nullptr;
    TreeNode* right = nullptr;
    …
};
```

Comment: Adding to this answer which is correct, just initialize child pointers to null

Comment: I indeed should have added a solution to my answer. Thanks for pointing that out; fixed.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is `SpecializedTreeParser2 _2;`. `TreeParser leftChild` and
>   `rightChild` are initialized fine, their `id` is printed. Check the output

Oh the joy of Undefined Behavior...

No, `TreeParser leftChild` and `rightChild` are not initialized fine and the problem is not `SpecializedTreeParser2 _2`.

The problem is that `TreeNode::left;` and `TreeNode* right;` are used uninitialized. This causes your program to have Undefined Behavior and the *beauty* of Undefined Behavior is that **the whole program** has undefined behavior, not just the use of the uninitialized variables. This means that although `SpecializedTreeParser1 _1` seems like it's ok, it is really not. The output that you see is a behavior falling unde undefined behavior. There is no point in analyzing where it comes from, why does `_1` seem to work and `_2` not. It's undefined behavior. Fix it and don't try to understand why this specific behavior.

---

Let me show you what I mean with a shorter example:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 24;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    int b; // uninitialized
    std::cout << b << std::endl; // <-- this line makes the WHOLE program to have UB
}
```

Now what are possible behaviors of the above program?

```
print "24"
print <garbage>
```

is possible and reasonable to expect

```
print "24"
print "0"
```

also possible

```
print "24"
<crash>
```

also not surprising

```
print <garbage>
print "24"
```

also possible... wait what? Yes!! The undefined nature of the program doesn't have to manifest at the line `std::cout << b << std::endl`. The whole execution of the program is undefined. **Anything** can happen!

All these are also possible:

```
<crash>
```

```
print "0"
print "0"
```

```
print "24"
print "24"
```

```
print "24"
print "0"
<crash>
```

```
print "Here be dragons"
```